# How to make a button click and change previously displayed text ( html )

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a button where when clicked, will change text previously displayed to something different. I have created a testing code but am unable to figure it out. I was wondering if someone could help? I'm required to use Javascript. Although this code displays the time when clicked, I need it to display text when clicked. I do not know how to modify this code to suit my needs

I have added internal commentary where i need help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Test</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =;
}
</script>


#need to change the code below to display text and not time

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using javascript when you are required to use java?

Comment: Whoops mis-typed there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap your new content with quotation marks `""`. Check the snippet below. Your code should work fine now if you click on the button.

In your original code, you had assigned an `onclick` attribute pointing at your function to the `<p id="demo"></p>` itself. As a result, your function was called only if you clicked on the text itself, not on the button.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your new content";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Test</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to display my custom text</button>
```

Comment: I need the code to display text when clicked, and not the time. I have searched many times and cannot find an answer. when I try and change it i just break the code. The quotation marks are not required.

Comment: In that case, you would need to make it so that the button runs myFunction() onclick, as at the moment it checks and updates the date onclick. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! If you feel like my answer helped, you could mark it as 'accepted'. This helps keep the focus on other questions which still don't have answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to display *some text*, add a string to your function. Something like this would work:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Some text";
}
```

See it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/r22jaffb/

Hope that helps.